# While using a single http client for several goroutines, does editing the transport on one thread affect the other?

Tags: http, go, goroutine, go-http

Lets say I have a global [`net/http`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http) [client](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Client) in my program. Within this program, I have several goroutines making requests with the same global [client](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Client). E.g.

Golang Pseudocode:

```golang
package main

func editTransportAndFetch(c *http.Client) {
    c.Transport = &http.Transport{
        // Make some unique change here
    }
    c.Get("https://www.google.com")
}

func main() {
    client := http.Client
    
    // Spawns 10 processes
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go editTransportAndFetch(client)
    }
}
```

In this pseudocode example, I demonstrate spawning 10 processes of the [`http.Transport`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Transport) being edited. In the case of this example, the same exact change is being made, so maybe interference isn't much of a concern. However, regardless, if these processes are happening concurrently, will one process updating the global client's transport interfere with the transport that a different process may be using?

My ultimate use case is that I would like to have a global client and be able to specify a custom [`DialTLSContext`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Transport.DialTLSContext) but only for certain requests. Requests that I don't want using the [`DialTLSContext`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Transport.DialTLSContext) may be running concurrently as well. I'm worried that if I edit the [`http.Transport`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Transport) of the client of one request that it may interfere and cause another request to also use [`DialTLSContext`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Transport.DialTLSContext) even though I don't want it to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you share the same client instance among multiple goroutines and if you modify that client from one of them, the behavior is undefined because it is a data race.

If you want to modify the client for some of the goroutines, there's no need to use a single client, and you can create a new client for every goroutine.

If you want to configure one client in main, and use that as a template for all goroutines, pass the client by value, not `*client`, so a copy of that template is passed to each goroutine, and each goroutine would work on its own copy, sharing the common `Transport` underneath. If you set the `Transport` to something else, then since the `Client` is a copy, it is still safe.

If you however modify something in the `Transport` instance (which is a `RoundTripper`), that is again a race condition. Don't do that.

Comment: Ok, so just to be clear. If I was using this in an API where certain endpoints were making unique requests, it would be better for a new client to be created on each request rather than have a single global client for the entire API?

Comment: If you are modifying the client, then yes. If somehow you can keep several different clients all configured, and then you don't modify them from the goroutines, then no.

Answer (score 1):

Http clients are thread safe according to the docs (https://golang.org/src/net/http/client.go):

Clients are safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines.